# SQL Update Row where First Row NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and need to update the first row for each SOrder from another table where the date value is null. In the example below I would evaluate whether `SOrder = 000791` and `REVDE2` is null, if so I would

```
SELECT SOrder, MyDates.NewDate FROM MyDates

UPDATE MyTable SET DateVate = MyDates.NewDate WHERE REVDE2 IS NULL
```

REVDE3 must remain null until the MyDates.NewDate > REVDE2 DateValue

```
SOrder      Line    FieldName       DateValue
000791      0001    REVDEL          01/12/2013
000791      0001    REVDE2          NULL
000791      0001    REVDE3          NULL
000992      0001    REVDEL          05/01/2014
000992      0001    REVDE2          08/12/2014
000992      0001    REVDE3          NULL
```

I'm not sure if a cursor would work, my only concern is the speed for running a cursor.

Comment: No Need for Cursor. I think you should be able to use a CTE to identify the 1st Null Row, and go from there. I'll work on a solution (unless someone else beats me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Fully Working Code Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd3d1/15

Here's the actual SQL Code that will do the updates. The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd3d1/15) above has the Schema and Inserts and Updates.

The assumption in this code is that `FieldValue` will not go beyond `REVDE9`, because if it hits `REVDE10`, then the sorting in the query will go whack!

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOrder ORDER BY FieldName ASC) AS rn
   FROM MyTable 
   WHERE DateValue IS NULL 
)
-- -- SELECT * FROM CTE
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateValue = md.NewDate
FROM MyTable mt 
    INNER JOIN MyDates md ON mt.SOrder = md.SOrder
    INNER JOIN cte c ON mt.SOrder = c.SOrder
        AND mt.FieldName = c.FieldName
        AND c.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SOrder ORDER BY FieldName) AS rownum
  FROM MyDates
  WHERE DateValue IS NULL
)
UPDATE t
SET DateValue = NewDate
WHERE rownum = 1
```